# setting up gitosis: avoiding duplicate user keys

Tags: ssh, git, ssh-keys

i'm following [this guide to setting up gitosis](http://www.howtoforge.com/setting-up-gitosis-on-ubuntu).

i run all this on the git server, including creating credentials for my user (in the git server) with the `ssh-keygen -t dsa` step

now, **from some other machine** i just want to do

```
git remote add origin git@GitServer:existingGitRepo.git
git push origin master:refs/heads/master
```

but this keeps asking for git@GitServer password! What the hell, later on the guide it says to add public keys from other users in there, i presume that amounts to run `ssh-keygen -t dsa` **on the other machine** and move the .pub file

what i'm concerned is that i will need to do this for each machine i will need to connect to this git repo??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gitosis uses the keys to identify "users" (normally, individual people committing code) since there is only one account ("git").  If you have one person who commits code from multiple computers, then that person will either need to create an ssh key on every machine and submit all of the different public keys to gitosis, or they will need to create one ssh key and copy the private key to all the different machines they will commit code from.  (Placing the same private key in multiple computers is generally frowned on, it increases the number of places the key can be stolen from).

Most [guides on multiple keys](https://github.com/hpfem/hermes/wiki/Gitosis-HowTo) seem to use `user@machine.pub` for the user's public key in gitosis, but one poster [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607479/git-server-frustration-gitosis-gitolite-etc) claims they just put all the public keys in one `user.pub` file and submitted that to gitosis.